# Get properties values from an object generic list c#

Tags: c#, generics

i am trying to get the values from the properties of my generic list but i get an error "T does not contain a definition for...."

```
 var values GetValues(Id);

 if (values != null)
        {
            CreateTable<Object>(values);
        }

/////
    private void CreateTable<T>(IList<T> array) 
    {

        foreach (item in array)
        {
          //Problem is here **** when trying to get item.tag
         var text = new TextBox(){ Text = item.Tag , ID = item.TagID.ToString() };

        }

    }
```

How can make it work with generics? Appreciate any help

Comment: don't use generics?  Generics are supposed to work with any type, but your code is wanting a specific type

Comment: I want to reuse the "CreateTable" code for different list of different types of objects. let's say: CreateTable(IList<Tags> array) ; CreateTable(IList<Contacts> array) and so on. and just change the textbox creation depending on the property names of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that you expect that an object of some arbitrary `T` type has a `Tag` and `TagID` property? Where are these properties defined? If they are defined on an interface, let's say

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Tag { get; }
    int TagID { get; }
}
```

then you don't need generics, you can redefine `CreateTable` as

```
private void CreateTable(IList<IITem> array)
{
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        //Problem is here **** when trying to get item.tag
        var text = new TextBox(){ Text = item.Tag , ID = item.TagID.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to reuse the "CreateTable" code for different list of different types of objects. let's say: CreateTable(IList<Tags> array) ; CreateTable(IList<Contacts> array) and so on. and just change the textbox creation depending on the property names of the object.

Comment: This assumes that `Tags` and `Contacts` both have the two properties `Tag` and `TagID`. If they do, having both of them implement the `IItem` interface from my answer is the perfect way to represent this property sharing. If they don't, you would need to also pass `CreateTable` a parameter for creating a `TextBox` based on a `T`, such as a `Func<T,TextBox>`, since it could not possibly know how to do this for arbitrary `T`.

Comment: yes, i understand what u say, the thing is i need to create the TextBox dinamycally and its properties depends on the values of the array. That is the issue. :(